# Как решить тригонометрическое уравнения с помощью sympy и чтобы ответ выводился нормальный

Tags: python, sympy

```
equation_user = 'cos(x) = ' + answer_eq_user
equation = 'cos(x) -' + str(answer_eq)
roots = solve(equation, x)
```

При решении с помощью функции solve, ответ выводится очень странный

```
2. cos(x) = -√2/2
Корнем уравнения является:  [pi/2 - I*asinh(sqrt(2)/2), 3*pi/2 + I*asinh(sqrt(2)/2)]
Но при другом уравнении выводится по человечески
3. cos(x) = √2/2
Корнем уравнения является:  [pi/4, 7*pi/4]
```

в переменной answer_eq_user лежит ответ со значком корня(√), в answer_eq лежит sqrt(a)/b.a и b рандомно берутся из картежа

Comment: можно более внятно объяснить?

Comment: Как заменить pi/2 - I*asinh(sqrt(2)/2), 3*pi/2 + I*asinh(sqrt(2)/2) на более корректный ответ. И такой ответ получается только если ответ с минусом

Comment: Открой учебник. Параграф комплексные числа. Там где минус и корень не сокращаются всегда будет в ответе i

Comment: Странно, что у вас вообще отрабатывает вариант с юникодным символом корня - у меня `solve` выдает на него ошибку `"SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier"`. Да и вообще непонятно как `sympy` должен понять где заканчивается аргумент корня - т.е. когда вы используете `sqrt(...)` - скобки однозначно определяют из чего извлекается корень, а при использовании `√` - непонятно что именно находится под корнем